# CSV module - 'for row in reader' - between Mac and Windows

Tags: python, windows, macos, csv, indexing

I developed some code on my Mac, using Wing IDE.  The code i developed, which makes use of the csv module, is working, and does what I want it to on my Mac.  The problem, though, is that the person I wrote it for needs to use it on Windows.  I wasn't concerned about the code, as I'm not using any escape characters.

The code looks like this:

```py
csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r')
csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
for row in csvreader:
   thisVariable = row[0]  # <<<--------
```

The 'arrow' I put in above is where the error is returned at, on the Windows machine.  Like I said, the code works fine on the Mac and, actually, this is pretty far down in the code that I have written.  There are other CSV files read from and written to above this statement, which use similar indexing.

I would really appreciate any ideas anybody might have regarding this issue!  Thanks!

Comment: The CSV documentation warns you to open the file in Binary mode, which you didn't do. Don't know if that would cause your error or not.

Comment: Note that the people talking about binary mode are correct for Python 2, and @shellster's advice about `newline=''` (and a text-mode file) is correct for Python 3. This is probably the cause of the error, but it'd be very useful in determining that if you posted the actual text/traceback of the error message.

Comment: `There are other CSV files read from and written to above this statement` -- Perhaps that line is somehow empty in that particular file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In Python 2**

You need to open the file as a binary file:

```
csvfile = open('file.csv', 'rb')
csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
for row in csvreader:
    thisVariable = row[0]
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader

---

**In Python 3**

You need to set newline='' in your open statement:

```
csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r', newline='')
csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
for row in csvreader:
    thisVariable = row[0]
```

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for all of the suggestions and advice.  I plan on implementing the 'test' for the bad data (using the if not row- continue).  The problem was with the escape character difference between Windows and Mac (linux)- \r\n and \n.  The solution was to, each time a file is read from or created and written to, include a "newline = ''" specification: open(filename, 'r', newline = '')!  Thanks again, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I can see two potential issues. First, you should be opening the file in binary mode:

```
csvfile = open('file.csv', 'rb')
```

Second, you may be dealing with having two different end of lines for two different OS's. You can avoid this by adding `U` after the mode:

```
csvfile = open('file.csv', 'rbU')
```

I also suggest protecting your users from bad data by testing the row. This makes the end result:

```
csvfile = open('file.csv', 'rbU')
csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
for row in csvreader:
   if not row:
      continue
   thisVariable = row[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) `csv.reader` should be passed a file opened in binary mode.
I.e.:

```
csvfile = open('file.csv', 'rb')
```

Without seeing the input file that causes the problem I can't be sure this will fix the problem, but it is likely to cause other bugs.